# Proprietary licensing combinations of non-copyleft software

Tags: licensing, distribution

Premise: Software Z (distributed as binary) includes software Y (MIT) and software X (MIT).

1. Does Software Z need to disclose it's inclusion of Y and X?
2. Software Z can be distributed under a proprietary license (given proper acknoledgemnent to Y and X)?

MIT License: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIT license only requires that the copyright notice and MIT license notice “shall be included”. I interpret this so that the notices must be discoverable and readable by an ordinary user. The MIT license has no further restrictions or requirements regarding distribution.

> Does Software Z need to disclose it's inclusion of Y and X?

Yes, the software must include the copyright and license notices for Y and X.
Good places for these notices are a manual, or an “About this software” menu item in a  GUI.

> Software Z can be distributed under a proprietary license (given proper acknoledgemnent [sic] to Y and X)?

Yes, the MIT license does not restrict downstream use of the software beyond the notice requirement. In particular, the MIT license is a *permissive* open source license that allows use in proprietary software.